# pfctl - How to forward ip address in Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: freebsd, pf

How to forward all traffic to an external site 172.16.19.211:5001 to 127.0.0.1:5000 ?

These docs have details about port forwarding but still ip forwarding is unclear.

http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html#tcpproxy

https://gist.github.com/kujohn/7209628